# Can't open Android studio. (issues related to JDK)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As mentioned in Question Title, I am unable to open  Android Studio.

When I am trying to open it, below message is shown:

```
"The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of 
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.8.0_31\bin;) does not point 
 to a valid JVM installation."
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to re-install the java sdk environment ?

Comment: What is the problem?  Help me. Please.~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing \bin from the end of your JAVA_HOME system variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your path variable for Java Installation is probably corrupt maybe due to a re-install or you didn't set it in the first place.

This can be easily fixed.

First install the latest version of **JAVA SE** from [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) webpage.

To set the **temporary path** of JDK (in windows), you need to follow following steps:

- Open command prompt
- copy the path of jdk/bin directory under program files. note it's "jdk" not "jre".
- write in command prompt: `set path=*copied_path*`

For Example:

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_23\bin
```

*where x.x.x are the jdk version related number*

It is useful to set the PATH environment variable permanently so it will persist after rebooting. You can read more about how to do this over here: [Set PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: It's very kind answer. but already this problem was solved. ~~!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, no problem. I was slow.